# Limit RewriteRule in htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

i got a [site](http://netbureau.com.br/) php based with some rules in the .htaccess file to get rid of file extentions in the url adress bar. Basically it takes `http://netbureau.com.br/en/about.php/` and turns it into `http://netbureau.com.br/en/about`.

Here are the lines in the htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The problem comes when i try to access the rss feed of the blog at `http://netbureau.com.br/blog/?feed=rss2` and when i try to set custom permalinks for the  blog at `http://netbureau.com.br/blog`. It gets messed up by the htaccess file.

So is there any way to disallow the RewriteRule for the `/blog` folder so that i can get back my rss link and set custom permalinks in the blog?

I know it's at the same time Wordpress related but it feels more connected to the htaccess file than Wp.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**:
I've set up the wordpress permalinks to the default structure which goes like this: `http://netbureau.com.br/blog/?p=123` This made my rss link back for good.
The remaining problem is that Wordpress gives me its own rewriterule which is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
```

Is there a way to to still use the first rule to apply to the whole site except the /blo/ folder and apply the WP rule only to the /blog/ folder?
I've tried different combinations but without luck so far. I could only have the site without the custom links for the blog or the custom blog links and a 404 on the pages of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

The `!^/blog/?` expression excludes any URI that starts with `/blog`

Comment: Thanks Jon for the help. I've updated my question after some more testings. Is there a way to apply different rules like the whole block you updated and after a new Rewriterule with conditions for a specific folder?